# Refactoring this code in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there an elegant way to accomplish this in Ruby?

```
if params[:limit] && params[:limit].to_i < 50
  @limit = params[:limit].to_i
elsif params[:limit] && params[:limit].to_i > 50
  @limit = 50
end
```

Comment: This should be asked on SO's new sibling site [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: limit = 0 and limit = -3 (and limit = -99999) are valid inputs?

Answer (score 3):

```
@limit = [params[:limit].to_i, 50].min unless params[:limit].nil?
```

Comment: :) hacker. But it can be little cleaner: `@limit = [params[:limit].to_i, 50].min if params[:limit]`

Comment: or `@limit = [l.to_i, 50].min if l=params[:limit]`

Comment: I think that's probably better. I'm inappropriately addicted to `unless`.

Comment: Also you can use `params[:limit].nil?` instead of `params[:limit] == nil` to be little more rubyish

Comment: Changed the response to use `nil?`. Very ruby.

Comment: I don't agree, in Ruby only nil and false are "false" in the truthness sense. So unless you really want to tell nil from false (not here), the simple, short, clear "if params[:limit]" is the best option. IMHO.

Comment: @tokland: I'm pretty sure that in this case, the question really is if `params[:limit:]` is nil. If it were false, this implies that the array is initialized with `false` as a value, and then these values are overwritten with integer or integer compatible values. Given that the actual test is for a `nil` value (false would be an error, and should show up as one!), I like `value.nil?`.

Comment: No, that's not true. It will always return something. `nil && true # => nil`

Comment: @Reins Henrichs: The original code sets a value to the instance variable if and only if the `if` statements return true. So if `params[:limit:]` is `nil` (for instance, if that array value doesn't exist) then while, yes, this would return `nil` if it were a complete method, it wouldn't 'return something' in the sense of setting a value to `@local`.

Comment: Given that instance variables are nil until proven guilty, conditionally initializing an instance variable has the same effect: some times it is nil, sometimes it is not. In fact, conditionally initializing any variable will initialize it to nil in the false case. Try it: `foo = 1 if false; foo # => nil`

Comment: @Rein Henrichs: `x = "happy"; if y and true then x = "sad"`. In both my code and the OP code, if y is nil then the value of x does not change. Either that or irb is totally lying to me. Perhaps `@local` already HAS a value, and the OP doesn't want to change it.

Comment: I'm not sure how I suggested that it would change in that case.

Comment: `unless params[:limit].nil?` - this part is unnecessary. `params[:limit].to_i` will convert `nil` to `0`

Comment: @Tumtu: But we may not *want* to set `@limit` to `0`. In fact, in the original code, the test has the effect of not changing the value of `@limit` if the array value does not exist. In order to replicate that behavior, the test for `nil` is required.

Answer (score 2):

```
limit = params[:limit] && params[:limit].to_i
@limit = limit && limit < 50 ? limit : 50
```

OR

```
@limit = params[:limit] && l=params[:limit].to_i && (l < 50 ? l : 50)
```

And I don't know if you would like to return `@limit` as nil in case if `params[:limit]` doesn't exist? Because in both cases `@limit` won't be initialized as in your example if there is no any `params[:limit]`

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
if params[:limit]
  @limit = [params[:limit].to_i, 50].min
end
```

Also, your current code may have a bug in it in that it doesn't set @limit if params[:limit] = 50 (you check for > 50 and < 50 but not = 50).

Edit: fl00r's implementation in philosodad's comment is pretty much the same but is more terse. Use his instead.

Comment: I think you want to replace your `max` with a `min`?

Comment: @philosodad Yeah, I caught that right after I entered it in. Fixed. :)

Comment: @sawa: If you enter `if nil? && true then puts "true" end` in irb, what does it return?

Comment: Don't you mean `== 50` (equality) rather than `= 50` (assignment)?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm No. My "= 50" was in the context of a sentence, not code. I think it's perfectly acceptable to say something like "check if x = 50" even though when implemented in code it would look like "if x == 50".

Answer (score 1):

```
@limit = params[:limit] && [params[:limit].to_i, 50].min
```

I think this is the most intention revealing approach.

Comment: Nice use of order of evaluation.

Comment: But there is a potential problem: if `@limit` already has a value, this code will reset that value to `nil`, which may not be the desired behavior.

Comment: That's easy enough to change with `||=`. Surely that could have been left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

not fully elegant, but shorter

```
@limit = params[:limit] ? (params[:limit].to_i < 50 ? params[:limit].to_i : 50 ) : nil
```

I would also consider using attribute of model with callbacks ... not sure how but that might work

Answer (score 0):

```
@limit = ((1..50).include? params[:limit]) || 50
```

(nil.to_i is 0, so no need to check it)

Comment: but what if `@params[:limit] == 0`?

Comment: what if `@params[:limit] = "3"` and `@params[:limit] = -3`

Comment: but does limit 0 or -3 really make sense? Judging from the name it is used for a database query or something like that. in SQL limit 0 returns zero rows (do you really want to do that), and limit -3 generates an sql error..

Comment: I don't know if it makes sense in context or not. I didn't vote this down, I was just pointing out a possible flaw.